# What is the meaning of "effet ’yau de poêle"?

Tags: expressions, humour

I have seen this under many videos on YouTube in discussions, but I cannot find out what it exactly means and what it refers to, what's the background, what is being referred to?

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yEg4Tc40rWM) is one example, look at the second comment.

I have read through this page but I absolutely do not understand anything: `https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/effet_’yau_de_poêle`

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the Wiktionary page, this expression is referring to meaningless puns made by appending an unrelated sentence starting with the last syllable(s) of an existing one. The figure of speech is named *[Dorica castra](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorica_castra)*.

The first and best know one is:

> *Comment vas-tu ?* (How are you ?)
>
> *Comment vas-**tu yau de poêle*** → *Tuyau de poêle* (Stove pipe)
>
> *Pas mal, et toi ?* (Not bad, what about you ?)
>
> *Pas mal, et **toi le à matelas*** → *Toile à matelas* (Mattress ticking)

from [Henri Maigrot](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Maigrot) published in the 1896 *[Almanach Vermot](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almanach_Vermot)*.

The nursery rhyme *[Trois petits chats](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trois_petits_chats)* is using a similar approach:

> Trois petits chats, trois petits chats, trois petits chats, chats, **chats**
>
> **Cha**peau de **paille**, ...
>
> **Paill**as**son**
>
> **Som**nam**bule**
>
> **Bul**le**tin**
>
> **Tin**tamare

and so on

Translations keeping the joke spirit are left as an exercice for the reader ...

Comment: C'est vrai menstupide…

Comment: Nicely played lmao.